# rpmbuild stripping out debug info for log4j?

Tags: java, log4j, rpmbuild

I am writing a Java standalone application with Spring. I use log4j for logging.

I use the following conversion pattern:

```
<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601}; %-5p - %C.%M(%L) - %m%n"/>
```

This works fine on my local PC. But when its built as an RPM (using rpmbuild) and deployed on the server, the class name, method name and line number show up as ?.?(?)

It seems to be that log4j does not have the debug info needed to display the class name, method name and line number.

I tried adding various versions of this :

```
%debug_package %{nil}
%define debug_package %{nil}
%define __strip /bin/true
```

but nothing fixed it.

Help?

UPDATE : This seems to be because I run the jar as : 
   java  -Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j.xml -jar my.jar

When I removed the log4j.configuration prop, log4j looked for the config file inside the jar, and printed the class info correctly. So it seems like defining the file externally creates the issue.
But I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '%' character is also used by rpm macros (and more) and
your content is being altered while reading the spec file.

You will need to escape (by using '%%' instead of '%')
some of the '%' characters to pass them through the rpmbuild parser.